# Find a subgame perfect equilibrium and a Nash equilibrium

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

I want to know if my thinking is correct. 
Look at the following game.

[image: Simultaneous game]

As the game has only one subgame (i.e., the game itself) then the Nash Equilibria will coincide with the subgame perfect equilibria.

In this case, we have two Nash equilibria: {U, u} and {D, d}. By my statement before, the subgame perfect equilibria will be {U, u} and {D, d} too.

Am I right?

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: The presentation suggests that it's a sequential game. If so, then "u" is not a strategy, so {U,u} is not a Nash equilibrium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As afreelunch only answered in the comment section, I'll answer it here.

The SPNE (Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium) is a refinement of the NE (Nash Equilibrium). So, let's call $S$ the set of all SPNE and $N$ the set of all NE in a game. Then:

$$S \subseteq N.$$

If the sequential game has only one subgame (see the subgame definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame)), the game itself, then we will have.

$$S = N.$$

And my reasoning was right.